# Vue3 and Quasar - custom component problem

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, quasar-framework

I want to test custom component in q-dialog. Here is code from example that I use:

```
<template>
    <q-btn @click="doClick">Dialog</q-btn>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useQuasar } from "quasar";
import CustomDialog from "@/components/common/login/CustomDialog.vue";

const { dialog } = useQuasar();

const doClick = () => {
  dialog({
    component: CustomDialog,
    // componentProps: {
    //   persistent: true,
    // },
    persistent: true,
  });
};
</script>
```

and CustomDialog:

```
<template>
  <q-dialog ref="dialogRef" @hide="onDialogHide">
    <q-card class="q-dialog-plugin">
      <q-card-section class="text-h6">Dialog Title</q-card-section>
      <q-card-actions :align="`right`">
        <q-btn flat label="Nevermind" @click="onDialogCancel" />
        <q-btn flat label="OK" @click="onOkClick" />
      </q-card-actions> </q-card
    ></q-dialog>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useDialogPluginComponent } from "quasar";

const {
  dialogRef,
  onDialogHide,
  onDialogOK,
  onDialogCancel,
} = useDialogPluginComponent();

const onOkClick = () => {
  onDialogOK();
};
</script>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CustomDialog",
};
</script>
```

When I click the button I have error in console: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'app.unmount')

Any idea what can be wrong?

I just copy-paste example from page where it is working, but with my project setup it does not work with custom component, with pre-defined components it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the dialog plugin in quasar.config.js see https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog#installation

```js
// quasar.config file

return {
  framework: {
    plugins: [
      'Dialog'
    ]
  }
}
```